# Default owners/permissions of files in user home directory

Tags: permissions, home-directory

I often see users that try to fix an issue and somewhere read or just try to recursively `chown` their home directory and sometimes even also reset permissions recursively to something like `rwxr-xr-x` or similar.

Imagine such an owner/permission massacre - are there critical files/directories that *need* special permissions or to be root-owned for the system to work?

Comment: Wat files are you talking about? Why would critical files owned by root be in a user home?

Comment: @mikewhatever I know at least three directories that need to be owned by root: `~/.gvfs/`, `~/.cache/gvfs-burn/` and `~/.cache/dconf`. Probably there are more.

Comment: `drwx------ 2 romano romano 4096 dic  2  2008 .gvfs` and never had any problem.... (see the date). Also `drwx------ 2 romano romano 4096 abr 28 14:57 .cache/dconf`

Comment: There are no "critical" files in the user's home the directory, if there are then it's the result of a very bad programming, since the user can remove them on purpose / by mistake in a flash. Unless it's a mistake, "critical" files are stored elsewhere.

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm that ~/.gvfs and ~/.cache/dconf on my system are both owned by root. I ran "sudo ls -Al" on both directories, and they're both empty. Although I've changed group and other permissions for documents, I have never ever run chown. So, root ownership for these two directories could well be normal, at least for Ubuntu 15.04. Also, I don't have a ~/.cache/gvfs-burn directory, or the ipc-admin directories mentioned by Byte Commander that are root-owned. But, the numeric-alpha-named file in ~/.dbus/session-bus is owned by Me, not root.

Comment: Oh, `ipc-admin` was the username. So `/home/ipc-admin/` is the same as `~/`...

Comment: Is this a default setup? Fresh installation? Never run `sudo` with any command that could touch your home directory? If not, this answer is a comment, at best.

Comment: For `.rpmdb` owned by root in your home read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/476941/40581). Summary: It's a bug and probably caused by DKMS trying to run RPM commands.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## NO file in `~` has to be owned by root.

If a software requires that a file in *your* home directory be owned by another user, it is a bug and should be reported as such.

Other than that, a common case involves two security-related software that require restricted permissions on certain files, namely:

1. SSH
2. GPG

### SSH

See `man ssh`, section `FILES`:

```
 ~/.ssh/config
     This is the per-user configuration file.  The file format and
     configuration options are described in ssh_config(5).  Because of
     the potential for abuse, this file must have strict permissions:
     read/write for the user, and not writable by others.  It may be
     group-writable provided that the group in question contains only
     the user.

 ~/.ssh/identity
 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
 ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     Contains the private key for authentication.  These files contain
     sensitive data and should be readable by the user but not acces‐
     sible by others (read/write/execute).  ssh will simply ignore a
     private key file if it is accessible by others.  It is possible
     to specify a passphrase when generating the key which will be
     used to encrypt the sensitive part of this file using 3DES.
```

Other files like `authorized_keys`, `known_hosts`, etc. should be writable only by the user, but can be world-readable.

### GnuPG

`~/.gnupg` (and contents) should be accessible only by you. With other permissions, GPG will complain about unsafe permissions.

Comment: So what about `~/.gvfs/`, `~/.cache/gvfs-burn/` and `~/.cache/dconf`? They're root-owned and I think they should be.

Comment: @ByteCommander nope. Use `sudo` with GUI programs, did you?

Comment: Not that I could remember it... I'm creating a new user and checking there. One moment, please.

Comment: @ByteCommander have a look: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=534284

Comment: The new user has indeed no root-owned files, but it does not have that `.gvfs`-directory at all yet. Hmm... So that means I was wrong there and `chown -R`-ing one's home directory is no problem at all? I swear I've read somewhere that a bunch of directories/files needs to be root-owned, especially those gvfs-related things.

Comment: I've found another two files owned by root that I am not sure whether it's right or wrong: `~/.dbus/session-bus/7ae519bec942595a6925fb2d5448031b-1` and `/home/ipc-admin/.aptitude/config`, much stuff under `/home/ipc-admin/.cache/pip/wheels/`, `/home/ipc-admin/.local/share/session_migration-(null)` and `/home/ipc-admin/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Can you imagine why those are root-owned on my system?

Comment: @ByteCommander presumably you used `sudo` with `aptitude`, `pip`, etc. and made some changes to configuration or something, and `sudo` didn't reset `$HOME`.

Comment: And how should I have used `aptitude` or `pip` properly without `sudo`? Do I need `sudo -H` or anything like that for those in future or what?

Comment: @ByteCommander depends on what you did. With `pip`, do `pip --user` without `sudo`.

Comment: But `pip --user` does not install python packages system-wide, which was intended.

Comment: @ByteCommander if that was the intention, then `sudo -i` or `sudo -H` probably should be used.

Answer (score 11):

In general files and directory in your home should be owned by you.
I have some strange root-owned files that are probably the result of executing `sudo` command; in fact there are programs that write things under `$HOME` (which well behaved programs requiring super-user privileges shouldn't do --- the effect is root taking ownership of files that should belongs to the user).
Normally deleting or re-owning them (depending on the file) does not create problems and often it solves some, like the infamous `.Xauthority` file --- and sometimes, after running `sudo dconf-editor`, you have things in configurations you can't modify anymore.

About special modes:

- scripts must be executable, of course, at least to the owner;
- so must be directories too (where `x` means right to cross);
- `.ssh` must be `drwx------` (0700) and the private keys in it `-rw-------` (0600)
- if you have a `Public` directory for sharing, it should be probably `drwxr-xr-x` (read permission to anyone) or `drwxrwxrwt` (with write permission and sticky bit, for enabling writing).

... I can't think to anything more needing special treatment.

Comment: So what about `~/.gvfs/`, `~/.cache/gvfs-burn/` and `~/.cache/dconf`? They're root-owned and I think they should be.

Comment: @ByteCommander --- all that things are owned by me in my system, and nothing misfunctions. Why do you think they must be owned by root? In `dconf` is *your* configuration, and the privileged command/daemon that does the mounting of partitions should switch ownership to you --- otherwise it's a bug. I commented this on your question.

Comment: I've found another two files owned by root that I am not sure whether it's right or wrong: `~/.dbus/session-bus/7ae519bec942595a6925fb2d5448031b-1` and `/home/ipc-admin/.aptitude/config`, much stuff under `/home/ipc-admin/.cache/pip/wheels/`, `/home/ipc-admin/.local/share/session_migration-(null)` and `/home/ipc-admin/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Can you imagine why those are root-owned on my system?

Comment: @ByteCommander Because the process creating them is running as root. (sorry for the 8-year delay in replying - you may know this by now :) )