# Which are the advantages of `sudo` defaulting to keep $HOME?

Tags: sudo, default

This question is a side-effect of [Default owners/permissions of files in user home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672907/default-owners-permissions-of-files-in-user-home-directory), and after a search which found [this Q&A on Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91384/how-is-sudo-set-to-not-change-home-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-disable-this-behavior).

When you use

```
sudo command
```

only a bunch of environment variable are preserved, for security reasons (although this point here is debated... but well). It is a matter of configuration defaults to decide if `$HOME` is preserved or not; in Ubuntu by default it is preserved and you need to use `sudo -H` to not preserve it (and setting it to the target user).

Check it (be careful with quoting, we don't want `$HOME` be resolved before calling `sudo`!):

```
[romano:~] % sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/romano
[romano:~] % sudo -H bash -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

I can see that preserving `$HOME` has the possible negative effect that you can use `sudo whatever` and if the program writes or modify files in `$HOME` (configuration, whatever) you will end with a file owned by root and  subsequently not modifiable by the normal user.

This can wreak havoc especially with new users... we have quite a bit of login loops due to a root-owned `.Xauthority` due to a (admittedly crazy) `sudo startx` in a terminal emulator under X, or unmodifiable configuration settings due to a misguided `sudo dconf-editor`, and so on.

On the other side, I see no positive effects. So I am now running with

```
Defaults        always_set_home
```

in my `/etc/sudoers`<sup>**(1)**</sup>, checking it:

```
[romano:~] % sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

The question: **What are the positive effects of preserving `$HOME` by default, if any?**

---

*Footnotes*

<sup>**(1)**</sup> Always, always, edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` and with a terminal (better a VC) with a `sudo -i` shell running. You will be grateful when you make some mistake cutting yourself out of superuser powers.

Comment: It is just the defaults the developers choose, you would have to ask on the mailing list for s detailed explanation. This is an advantage of sudo vs su, sudo has more configuration options. Personally, I use sudo -i , see also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question - the OP is asking whether there are any benefits to `sudo` without `-i` or `-H` - or why neither of those are on by default.

Comment: Head to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/889936 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1373495

Comment: Another user probably bit by this: http://askubuntu.com/a/732521/16395. I think that this is no opionin-based, and the correct answer is that there are no upsides and a lot of downsides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in pointing out potential problems with `sudo` and applications that write files in `$HOME`.

The reason for this behaviour would not really be a conscious developer choice, but more that it wasn't really necessary for the intended purposes for which  `sudo` was first conceived: for use with simpler unix-style applications that just take some input and return some output in a predictable manner and then return.  It wouldn't originally have been designed to contend with larger applications that run interactively and manage their own files.

As rightly pointed out, `sudo -i <command>` is good for any application that's *interactive* (think of the *i* as standing for *interactive*, even though that's not what it stands for).  `-i` has further theoretical benefits over `-H` in that the target user's environment, eg `.profile`, is read too.

There's also `gksudo <command>` for graphical interactive applications, but `sudo -i <command>` works well enough for those too.

If you don't want to type `sudo -i <command>` all the time you could create a script/alias for it I guess.

Comment: Well, `sudo -i` gives you an interactive shell which sometime can be dangerous (the typo in a command can happen to even the most senior here...). `sudo -H` is ok, and you really do not need an alias, it's a matter of configuration file --- as I shown in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to refer to `sudo -i <command>`, which runs the single command in a login shell and then exits, not `sudo -i` without a command.