# Gimp does not open on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gimp

How to open gimp ,

i have installed gimp on ubuntu 14.04 from the software center but when i click the icon nothing happens , then i typed gimp on the terminal and i get the following message

"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

also there is a software crash notification
[image: gimp crash notice]

ps -aux | grep gimp terminal result is

11724  0.0  0.0  15944  2204 pts/0    S+   17:48   0:00 grep --color=auto gimp

Things that i have tried :

uninstalling and reinstalling it using ubuntu software center

uninstalling and reinstalling it using synaptic manager

performing the following commands

```
  sudo apt-get autoremove gimp gimp-plugin-registry

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install gimp
```

nothing is working

what can i do now , gimp was my favorite image editor back in windows and now i am not able to use it in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try unistalling it then installing it again using the method in this question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-the-latest-gimp-version-available

Comment: thanks for the reply , tried the method in the question but gimp still does not open

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Did you get any errors? Kindly edit your question and include this information.

Comment: Try to remove (backup first) the directories (in your home) of gimp defaults. In my system they are `~/.gimp-2.6/` and `~/.gimp-2.8`. You can find yours with the command `find ~ -name "*gimp*"` --- be careful though. Another way to find the problem is to run `strace -f gimp` and trying to see where it chokes exactly (warning --- very big output expected).

Comment: no its not opening : (

Comment: Is there a reason why you would rather install packages from third-party repositories instead of upgrading your system to a more recent version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution that worked for me . Just created a folder name .gimp-2.8 in my home directory

```
mkdir .gimp-2.8
```

**do not use sudo** and it solved my problem :)

Comment: Ah --- ok. Got it. Never use graphical application as root, or at list call that with `sudo -H` (this is due to a in my opinion worng `sudo` default in Ubuntu, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/673022/which-are-the-advantages-of-sudo-defaulting-to-keep-home -- closed wrongly, I think)